# What is this kind of drill-bit-like milling cutter called?

Tags: machining

I've seen a video with a tool I had never seen before but in the mean time this video has been removed, So I will try to describe instead:

The general machine is a kind of CNC saw. It looks like a router, but with only **2 axis**, and the material is transported by a conveyor belt instead of being attached to a plate. And the reason it MUST be like that, is that instead of using a classical milling cutter on a third axis spindle, this specific "milling cutter" is like a vertical saw, but rotating instead of vertically moved, and it's shaped like a drill bit with attachments on both ends (See illustration - fabricated from a drill bit picture).
[image]

what is it called ? what keyword will I need to google it ?
[image]

Comment: please add a reference to the image source into your question ... edit the question ... do not add comment

Comment: What do you mean : "a reference" ? I thought I made myself clear : What I saw, is a video that has been removed in the mean time, and since I didn't expect it to disappear, I didn't think about making a screenshot in time. For this reason, I FABRICATED those picture from a picture of a drillbit and a picture of a chuck found on the net. Both those picture can be considered às DRAWINGS I made to illustrate my question.

Comment: Technically, since your illustration is based on "a picture of a chuck found on the net" then it is derived from someone else's work and should be credited. The site policy is explained here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.

Comment: Oh, THAT's what you were talking about... hmmm... I don't think I could retrieve that info easily, especially since those picture are very general topics with nothing artistic, often come from chinese sites who sell that product but often illustrate them from stolen pictures or videos - and the picture were very seriously reprocessed by myself to create my illustration... This is mostly my work :-/

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're describing a CNC router with a unique tool configuration – a rotating, drill bit-shaped saw on a two-axis system with material transportation via a conveyor belt. The tool's design, resembling a drill bit with attachments on both ends, suggests a specialized cutting mechanism.

Comment: You have basically repeated the description from the OP's question. You haven't answered the actual question, "What is this kind of tool called?" Welcome to E.SE.